# Android: how to get a real screen size in dp (density-independent pixel)

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, viewport

I needed to write a plugin for Unity to get the screen size in **dp** (density-independent pixel) aka viewport size.

For example: One Plus 3 has a resolution of 1080x1920**px**. And its viewport size is 480x853**dp**.

---

So I'm using code like this:

```
UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getResources().getConfiguration()
```

And then I use the fields `screenWidthDp` and `screenHeightDp`. However `screenHeightDp` returns the height minus the size of the status bar.

Also, I can get the size of the screen in pixels and divide it by density, but I'm not sure if it will return the correct result in all cases.

Please tell me how can I get the full height and width of the screen in **dp**?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but maybe [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/41020/how-to-get-the-screen-size.html) can help you out